# How to disable Slack URL suggestion?

Tags: slack-api, slack

I want to send a direct message to a Slack user which contains a website link in its text. Here is the text,

> var msgText="Find us on < http://www.google.com|Google>";

and then POST,

> method: "POST", 
>   url: "https://slack.com/api/chat.postMessage",
>   body: { "token": slackBotToken, "as_user":true, "channel":"@UserId","text":msgText}

This is what I get on my Slack account,

[image]

I want to remove the URL suggestion, any idea how to do that?

Thanks

Comment: Take a look at the `unfurl_links` property: https://api.slack.com/docs/message-attachments#unfurling

Comment: @WilhelmKlopp Thanks for your suggestion but unfortunately that didn't work.

Comment: @WilhelmKlopp I agree with @Chethan Shetty. I've already tried the `unfurl_links` parameter, and it doesn't stop Slack from causing a request to my server (which in my case is to a URL that would require authentication, so it's causing an exception). https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/97867/27487 is interesting, but my Slack dashboard Attachments page says "To blacklist a link, just click the X in the upper left of an attachment and follow the instructions. Blacklisted links will appear here." I don't think that's relevant for me since my problematic Slack messages don't have attachments.

Comment: I found this setting, which works if you don't mind globally blocking all unfurling, but I'd still love to know how to get the `unfurl_links` argument to work as expected: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/76085/27487

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got the answer from Slack Support, and I have verified that he is correct:

> Thanks for getting in touch, and sorry for the troubles with
>   unfurling. It's quite hidden in our documentation (we'll make it more
>   clear), but in order to completely prevent link unfurling within a
>   particular message, you'll need to set both `unfurl_links` and
>   `unfurl_media` to `false`.

Comment: This won't appear to work in the Slack "message builder" tool, but it does work when used with the actual API.

Comment: It might help to mention that this should work for "Attachments" type of message building and that it is not available for "Blocks" which is a newer form of message building. See here (https://api.slack.com/reference/messaging/link-unfurling) that after the deactivating unfurling section they put a "upgrade to blocks" documentation section.

Comment: This is working for blocks now. Just pass this args in chat_postMessage